# D3: gauge chart with growing arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to achieve something like a growing arc which indicates 5 levels (see picture). My data has only an integer value which is between 1-5. You can ignore the icon in the middle for now. Is there any possibility to achieve something like that in d3? I couldn't find any example for this. Moreover I tried it with a cut off pie (donut) chart approach, but I couldn't make the growing arc... I would appreciate any help! Thanks for that.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. Hopefully someone else comes up with a d3 solution. Otherwise I have to accept one of your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with d3 without dependency on external images, SVG sprites or anything in the DOM — just d3.js.

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je57f9vy/1/). The implementation is explained below.
But also, here's a [more advanced](http://jsfiddle.net/je57f9vy/4/) fiddle that animates a clip-path over the growing arc. Check out [its predecessor](http://jsfiddle.net/je57f9vy/3/) to see how the mask looks without clipping.

First, you need to represent the graphics as an array of data that you bind to with d3. Specifically, you need a color and a "line command" (the string you assign to d as in `<path d="...">`. Something like this:

```
var segmentData = [
    { color:"#ED6000", cmd:"M42.6,115.3c5.2,1.5,11,2.4,16.8,2.4c1.1,0,2.7,0,3.7-0.1v-2.2c-7,0-13.1-1.3-18.8-3.6L42.6,115.3z" },
    { color:"#EF7D00", cmd:"M25.7,99.3c4.3,4.7,9.5,8.6,15.3,11.3l-1.4,3.8c-6.9-2.4-13.2-6.1-18.6-10.8L25.7,99.3z" },
    { color:"#F4A300", cmd:"M23.7,97c-5.2-6.4-8.8-14-10.3-22.4L2.9,75.7c2.9,10,8.5,18.9,15.8,25.9L23.7,97z" },
    { color:"#F7BC00", cmd:"M13,71.5c-0.2-2-0.4-4-0.4-6c0-10.7,3.4-20.6,9.2-28.8L9.4,28.3c-5.6,9-8.9,19.6-8.9,30.9  c0,4.6,0.6,9.1,1.6,13.5L13,71.5z" },
    { color:"#FFCF36", cmd:"M63,15.7V0.8c-1-0.1-2.5-0.1-3.7-0.1c-19.9,0-37.5,9.9-48.1,25l12.7,8.6C33.1,23,46,15.7,63,15.7z" }
];
```

Then you need an empty `<svg>` and probably a `<g>` within it, into which to draw the graphics:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 125)
    .attr("height", 125);

var gauge = svg.append("g");
```

Then you use d3 binding to create the segments:

```
var segments = gauge.selectAll(".segment")
    .data(segmentData);
segments.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
    .attr("d", function(d) { return d.cmd; });
```

This just creates the graphic, but doesn't color it based on an integer value. For that, you can define an `update` function:

```
function update(value) {
    segments
        .transition()
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return i < value ? d.color : "#ccc";
        })
}
```

Calling `update(4)` will color all but the last segment. Calling `update(0)` color none (leaving all of them gray).

In the fiddle, there's also a `tick()` function that calls `update` with a new value on a setTimeout basis, but that's just for demo.

Finally, if you wish, you can wrap all that code up and create a reusable component by following the advice in [this article].(http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks you for that! Furthermore it would be interesting how you achieved the segment cmd data.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that the path data came from the svg that @krzysiej linked to below. Not sure where that svg came from.

Comment: @meetamit how do I expand the number of segments (e.g. make the arc go further than 5 arcs?) Where did you get the data for the line command?

Comment: @BartVanRemortele the path data came from the [svg that krzysiej linked to below](http://d7mj4aqfscim2.cloudfront.net/images/skill-strength-sprite2.svg). Not sure where that svg came from. To add arcs you would need to open the SVG using Illustrator or Inkscape, modify it there, then save it out as SVG again and extract the paths data out of that output. Alternatively, you might be able to use ellipse geometry to calculate and derive that path, but I'm not sure how feasible that it.

Answer (score 4):

since it is relatively simple picture, I'd use a sprite, with 5 variations. 
That would be much easier than using d3 and gives the same result.
(you could use some online tool like http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/ )

Comment: as an option that saves traffic I would suggest only two images: one completely full and one completely empty. They should be placed identically positioned absolute. And _full_ image should be clipped by a container. Container size controlled from javascript... But generally I assume approach correct since d3 is not intended for such stuff

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mimic duolingo progress images you can just simply copy their solution with own images. They are using sprites as this one: http://d7mj4aqfscim2.cloudfront.net/images/skill-strength-sprite2.svg not the d3.js approach. This will save you a lot of time and effort.