# JS Gauge with growing arc

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, kendo-dataviz, fusion

Does anyone know of a JavaScript charting library that is capable of drawing a a gauge like this:

[image: Gauge chart]

I've already looked at Highcharts, Kendo UI and FusionCharts, but I couldn't find any samples with a non-constant width of the arc...but that could also be because I don't even know what to search for exactly.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155600/d3-gauge-chart-with-growing-arc) which seems to go in the right direction, but I'd rather not have to draw SVG myself if there's an out of the box solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else ever needs something like that, I ended up building it myself using D3. Full animated sample is available at http://jsfiddle.net/0288wscf/11/

```
var domain = [1, 100];

var angleScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(domain).range([minAngle, maxAngle]);
var radiusScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(domain).range([radius - minWidth, radius - maxWidth]);
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(domain).range([minColor, maxColor]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 2 * radius)
    .attr("height", 2 * radius);

var gauge = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")")

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radiusScale)
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .startAngle(angleScale)
    .endAngle(angleScale);

function update(n) {    
    var ticks = gauge.selectAll(".tick").data(d3.range(1, n), function(d) { return d; });

    ticks.enter()
         .append("path")
         .attr("class", "tick")
         .attr("stroke", colorScale)            
         .attr("d", arc)
         .attr("stroke-width", tickThickness)
         .attr("opacity", 0)
         .transition()
         .delay(enterDuration)
         .attr("opacity", 1);

    ticks.exit()
         .transition()
         .delay(exitDuration)
         .remove();
}
```